# Core Data, sorted search — is it possible?

Tags: cocoa, search, core-data

In my application i have to search for strings from an array of NSStrings in an array fetched by a core data request. The fetched array contains about 30,000 entries (and it is bound to grow), and the strings array can be up to hundreds of thousands of strings. 
What i do now is select all the strings from the Core Data storage, and loop through the strings array, create an NSPredicate and use it to filter the Core Data fetched array. 
I thought that if i sort both of the arrays beforehand that would allow to narrow down each consequent search, but is it possible at all to search an array beginning from a certain position using a predicate?

Best regards, 
Timofey.

Comment: You can sort the results returned from the fetch request by calling `-[NSFetchRequest setSortDescriptors:]`.  Or do you need something more complex than that?

Comment: Well, I know that. The thing is that the first thing that comes into mind is to compare the array elements, so to speak, manually. I.e. you iterate over one of the arrays, compare the current element to the current element of another array, if they are equal, you proceed to the next elements of both arrays, if they are not, you proceed to the next element of one of the arrays (now that i've written it, it seems like _the_ reasonable solution). But is there anything more "automatic" for that? It looks like a common enough taks.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. Are you trying to do a union of two sets of strings? Both potentially very large. Are one or both stored in core data?

Comment: Not exactly. I need to know if the strings that i have as an input array (not stored) are present in the store, and if they are, what attributes they have in the persistent store. Only one of them is stored.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to fetch all the string from Core Data. It's slow and takes up tons of memory. Just use NSPredicate to filter out the string you wanted, give it NSFetchRequest and fetch only the result you wanted. You can also add NSSortDescriptor to NSFetchRequest to have your result sorted.

Comment: In fact, fetching all the Entities from the datastore turned out to be extremely fast in comparison with using an NSPredicate to filter the result. I do sort the entities by one of their string attributes, and that allows me to compare them with another sorted array of strings. As to memory, as far as i understood, Core Data takes care of that, fetching only a limited part of the whole resultset only when the corresponding elements are accessed.